# Cross domain login via PrincipalContext

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have a weird problem. I want to check user and password is valid on 2 domains with trust.

```
List<string> definedDomains = new List<string>();
definedDomains.Add("DomainA");
definedDomains.Add("DomainB");

bool isValid = false;

foreach (string domain in definedDomains)
{
    using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
    {
        isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials("userB", "password");
```

And here is wierd part: on DomainA, and UserB with valid password ValidateCredentials return true. And later

```
PrincipalContext yourDomain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain);
UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(yourDomain, "UserB");
```

FindByIdentity method return null.

How to validate only in one domain on the time?

Answer (score 0):

You can validate cross-domain credentials because the specified domain forwards the query on to the user's domain, but you cannot load principal information from a domain that does not contain the user.

The `PrincipalContext` defines the boundaries within which `FindByIdentity` will search. This can be a whole domain, a particular OU within a domain, but you can't find results outside the context.